# C#: "using" directive and try/catch block

Tags: c#, database, try-catch, using-statement

I know how to use try/catch block in case of database calls and know how to use "using" directive in context of using try/finally construction as well.

But, can I mix them? I mean when I use "using" directive can I use try/catch construction as well because I still need to handle possible errors?

Comment: Sure you can "mix" them. Is there a particular case that you do not understand?

Comment: In my case I have the code that interacts with database in WCF service. Is the usage the same in that case as well?

Comment: Ok. This is new question and I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it:

```
using (var con = new SomeConnection()) {
    try {
        // do some stuff
    }
    catch (SomeException ex) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

`using` is translated by the compiler into a `try..finally`, so it's not very different from nesting a `try..catch` inside a `try..finally`.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use both together.

A `using` block is basically just a bit of syntactic sugar for a try/finally block and you can nest try/finally blocks if you wish.

```
using (var foo = ...)
{
     // ...
}
```

Is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var foo = ...;
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    foo.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is perfectly valid:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    try
    {
        // Do something with the memory stream
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something to handle the exception
    }
}
```

The compiler would translate this into

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
try
{
    try
    {
        // Do something with the memory stream
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something to handle the exception
    }
}
finally
{
    if (stream != null)
    {
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Of course this nesting works the other way round as well (as in nesting a `using`-block within a `try...catch`-block.

Answer (score 0):

A `using` such as:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    connection.Open
    // do some stuff with the connection
}
```

is just a syntactic shortcut for coding something like the following.

```
SqlConnection connection = null;
try
{
   connection = new SqlConnection();
   connection.Open
   // do some stuff with the connection
}
finally
{
   if (connection != null)
   {
      connection.Dispose()
   }
}
```

This means, yes, you can mix it with other try..catch, or whatever. It would just be like nesting a `try..catch` in a `try..finally`.
It is only there as a shortcut to make sure the item you are "using" is disposed of when it goes out of scope. It places no real limitation on what you do inside the scope, including providing your own `try..catch` exception handling.